# Any tool/approach to find out plsql code coverage?

Tags: code-coverage

I am searching a way to find out plsql code coverage ( similar to jacoco) when the tests were integration tests (ran through an automation testing tool).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There is a package you can install called DBMS_profiler. With this, you can start a profile and Oracle will store data in special tables. Then stop the profile and report from those tables.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.toadworld.com/BLOGS/tabid/67/EntryID/267/Default.aspx has info about checking code coverage using the PL/SQL profiler.